# SQL last value aggregation is giving first value with ordered inner query

Tags: sql, exasol

Hi I have below query

```
SELECT
    CLUSTER_ID AS CLUSTER_ID,
    "date"
FROM
    HISTORY
GROUP BY
    CLUSTER_ID,
    "date"
ORDER BY
    CLUSTER_ID,
    "date"
```

with below output

```
1   2023-02-27
1   2023-03-01
1   2023-03-06
1   2023-03-13
1   2023-03-20
1   2023-03-27
1   2023-04-01
1   2023-04-03
```

when used above query as inner query as below, my expectation is to get last date which is **2023-04-03** but to my surprise it is giving first value which is **2023-02-27**

```
SELECT
    LAST_VALUE(CLUSTER_ID),
    LAST_VALUE("date")
FROM
    (

        SELECT
            CLUSTER_ID AS CLUSTER_ID,
            "date"
        FROM
            HISTORY
        GROUP BY
            CLUSTER_ID,
            "date"
        ORDER BY
            CLUSTER_ID,
            "date")
    GROUP BY
        CLUSTER_ID
```

It is giving expected value **2023-04-03** when **DESC order** is used in inner query like below

```
SELECT
    LAST_VALUE(CLUSTER_ID),
    LAST_VALUE("date")
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CLUSTER_ID AS CLUSTER_ID,
        "date"
    FROM
        HISTORY
    GROUP BY
        CLUSTER_ID,
        "date"
    ORDER BY
        CLUSTER_ID,
        "date" DESC)
GROUP BY
    CLUSTER_ID
```

can someone please explain the execution flow of the query

Comment: Ordering in subqueries really won't matter, its sort of a waste of processing. the LAST_VALUE() function itself is where you would instruct it to use DESC ...   LAST_VALUE(c) OVER(ORDER BY c DESC)

Comment: Thank you, but I see the ordering in sub query is impacting the output that too first is giving last of ordered result from inner query and vice versa, looking to understand execution flow

Comment: Can you compare and share the profiles of both queries?
https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/performance/profiling.htm